# DC to AC welder accessory circuit

Tags: ac, relay, switching, waveform

I want to create an external accessory for a DC welder which would create square wave ac. This would be in the ball park of 20V 130A 60hz. My idea is to use solid state relays to flip the polarity of electrode and ground, this flipping signal could be altered to modify the positive/negative delay and the frequency.

My question is whether this is fundamentally flawed. Are solid state relays able to cope with most of their load capacity whilst being switched rapidly? Would there likely be a delay between swapping polarity which could be long enough for the arc to be extinguished?

If this is possible then perhaps this would be a way to weld aluminium occasionally without spending the not inconsiderable price-tag of a true AC welder.

Hope this isn't too vague, simple or silly.

Comment: I guess, you can buy a TIG with AC output. Not only you will not have chunk of transistors lying unprotected, but also you will spend less and you'll get a useful machine.

Comment: Also, pure square wave welding on aluminum isn't often used. The "hard edges" of the waveform lead to very-high-frequency components that tend to make the arc less stable. Saving up for a simple AC TIG would probably be better and safer.

Comment: I know what you can buy. The idea is to provide the basic functionality for occasional use. Reasonable quality dc machines are a fraction of the cost of compatible quality ac. I'm interested in whether the idea is possible and what would be important in making it functional.

Comment: @FredWilson They are expensive for simple reason: the DC/AC output converter that you wan't to add. You won't make big deal adding something yours.

Comment: What is the input voltage?

Comment: It is never cheaper to make one of something than it is to buy one of something that is made by the 100's of thousands or millions. Especially if your time is worth something. Also, testing requires a lot of expensive equipment. You can't build something like this without testing it. Do you have a 150 Amp current probe and oscilloscope? Something like that? You can't test it without blowing up a few pieces. So you can't really just make one. You will need to build 3 or 5 or 20. It might be a good learning experience, and that is a reason to do it. But saving money is not realistic.

Comment: You need voltage rating on them to cope with the open circuit voltage of your welder, which I suspect would be around 100 V. If you do build this H-bridge output, PLEASE do report back on your findings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of high current contactors or relays for the last stage of the switcher, instead of solid state relays. The time should be controlled so that one relay opens before the other closes, and vise versa.  You decide how much time to allow for the transition. There is no reason why it would not work.  Just keep safety in mind.